# HTTPServlet Request.getInputStream() always receiving blank line

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, httpwebrequest

The client:

```
    public List<String> post(List<String> toWrite){
        String result = "";
        List<String> allResults = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            initializeOutputStream();
            for(int i = 0; i < toWrite.size(); i++){
                out.write(toWrite.get(i));
                out.newLine();
            }
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
            initializeInputStream();
            while((result = in.readLine()) != null){
                allResults.add(result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }

        return allResults;
    }

One of the attempts at the host:

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> incoming = new ArrayList<String>();

//      BufferedReader in = req.getReader();
//
//      String tmp = in.readLine();

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();  
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;  
        try {  
          InputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream();  
          if (inputStream != null) {  
           bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
        inputStream));  
           char[] charBuffer = new char[128];  
           int bytesRead = -1;  
           //while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
           while(bytesRead != -1){
            stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);  
           }  
          } else {  
           stringBuilder.append("");  
          }  
        } catch (IOException ex) {  
          throw ex;  
        } finally {  
          if (bufferedReader != null) {  
           try {  
            bufferedReader.close();  
           } catch (IOException ex) {  
            throw ex;  
           }  
          }  
        }  
        String body = stringBuilder.toString();  
        System.out.println(body);

        out.println(body);

//      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));        
//      
//      String tmp = "";
//      
//      //while(!(in.ready())){}
//      
//      while((tmp = in.readLine()) != null){
//          System.out.println(tmp);
//      }
//
//
//      out.println(tmp);

        out.println("end");

    }
```

Please note the commented out lines- thats one of the many other attempts I've tried to get stuff from the client.

System.out.printlns and out.printlns from the servlett all return a blank line. The "end" at the end of the program returns without problem. It is not a problem of reading multiple lines back on the client side- if I put multiple out.println's, then I read them fine. The system.out.println() for the inputstream also returns blank. The status code is 200, so there seems to be no connection errors.

Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like your while loop doesn't do anything here, because in your case, `bytesRead` is always -1 thus it will never get into the loop at all, and further, you don't use your `bufferedReader` at all to read from the input stream:-

```
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while (bytesRead != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

Try this:-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(1000);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(req.getInputStream());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    String body = stringBuilder.toString();

    System.out.println(body);
    out.println(body);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below lines

```
while(bytesRead != -1){
        stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);  
}
```

with

```
bufferedReader.read(charBuffer);
String str = new String(charBuffer);
System.out.println(charBuffer);
```

Hope it works.