# Jersey request.getInputStream()

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

```
@POST
@Path("/getphotos")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getPhotos() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    return "ok";        
}
```

The code above is for my server.
But in this code, the String "line" has no value.(always)
Is there any problem with the code?

---

client side code

```
    String message = "message";
    URL url = new URL(targetURL);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(message);
```

Comment: Below link will help you to read line from request.
[Link to read line][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175203/httpservlet-request-getinputstream-always-receiving-blank-line

Comment: Its a bad idea to use buffered readers to read (presumably) non-text information. Whats the incoming content type and are you sending it as multipart data?

Comment: incoming data is String now, but later it would be changed to Json also sending type will be Json

Comment: i think **requst.getInputStream()** it's not working with jersey

Comment: @JuengwooYu - `request.getInputStream()` works just fine, assuming you have a valid handle to the request, and the stream hasn't already been consumed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ***can*** manually consume a request's data in Jersey, as long as you have a valid handle to the actual `HttpServletRequest`. On a slight side note, keep in mind that you can only consume the request body ***once***:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@POST
@Path("/")
public Response consumeRequest() {
    try {
        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        String line = null;
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(2048);

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        final String data = buffer.toString();
        return Response.ok().entity(data).build();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("No data supplied").build();
    }
}
```

*Side note: Libraries like Apache Commons IO provide robust functions for reading IO data*

Comment: thanks for you answer. in upper code, StringBuffer "buffer" would be assigned the data from client. right?

Comment: @JuengwooYu - yes, the input stream data is accumulated into the buffer line by line. And at the end the entire thing is flipped into a string.

Comment: @JuengwooYu - thats the most likely explanation, yes. Add your client code to the original question.

Comment: @JuengwooYu - two quick things, you need to set the request method on the url connection to `POST`, and you need to flush the output stream after writing to it.

Comment: urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); this code means this is post type

Comment: but can you tell me what is the error from my client side code?

Comment: @JuengwooYu - your code looks for the most part fine. Make those changes I suggested, and also, you might want to add a content type header (`urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");`).

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you please feel free to upvote/accept it! And good luck with the rest of the coding.